# What does a WHERE clause of "sql was here" mean?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me understand or post any ideas concerning this where clause?

```
sql was here
```

I've changed the table name, but other than that, any idea what the developer was trying to do here?

There is nothing else after that, that's the where clause.

Comment: Does the query work? What are the types of the columns? What data does it take as input, for example? What output does it give for this data?

Comment: Yes, the query runs, the date fields are DATE.

Comment: Shouldn't the result of ifnull() be tested? Or is the default test when none is provided true / bool?

Comment: Well, I guessed from the names it's they are dates, but it would be useful to know if `table.date_field` or `table2.exit_date` are declared DATE NULL or DATE NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If `(table.date_field = (select max(table2.exit_date) from table as table2))` is null the it'll return `1=1`, which basically means there's no where clause at all.

Now let's look into that nasty expression. I can only assume that if "a = b" is not true then that's also equivalent to null, otherwise it seems like the first branch would always happen. It looks like it's trying to say "if the latest exit date is equal to the date field, select those, otherwise have no where clause". However, I don't think that this will work at all. It really looks like either way, each row will be selected.

Comment: `"a = b" is not true then that's also equivalent to null`: a = b returns NULL if either A or B are NULL. If `a = b` is false, it returns 0 which isn't the same as NULL.

Comment: @somedev: if the "nasty expression" returns `false`, it *won't* return the row. If it returns either `true` or `NULL`, it *will* return the row.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL `ifnull` function returns the first argument if it is not null, otherwise the second argument.  This looks like it tries to compare table.date_field to the max(table2.exit_date), and return true if the comarison was not possible due to nulls.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like he is trying to find the row where `table.date_field` is equal to the maximum of `table.exit_data`. There is a check for null which I think would happen in any of these cases:

- `table` is empty
- all rows in `table` have `exit_data` set to `NULL`
- `table.date_field` is `NULL` for the row in question

In any of these three cases, the row will be returned. I don't understand why he uses the string `'1=1'` instead of, to give some examples: `1=1`, `1` or `true`, but it appears to work fine. In the first case I assume that there will be no rows in the result set anyway (depending on the rest of the query) so he was probably trying to handle one of the other two cases - I'd guess the last one.

This is only an explanation of what is happening. To understand *why* he is doing this, it would help if you gave a little more context.

Comment: But the result isn't checked, so the whole thing is pointless, correct? Or is the default a test for true if nothing is given?

where ifnull() = true ?

Comment: somedev: No, it's not required to test it - it works fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

- MySQL is nonstandard in that *true* is really equal to the numeric value 1.  Any expression that evaluates to *true*, or any nonzero value, satisfies the condition.

  ```
  mysql> CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT 1=1 AS f;
  mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE foo;
  CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `f` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
  ```

  So the following WHERE clause is legal in MySQL, but not in most other SQL databases:

  ```
  ... WHERE 1;
  ```
- Some people use `1=1` as a placeholder condition meaning *true*, but putting it in a string is meaningless because SQL expressions have no equivalent to an `eval()` function as other languages have.  In this case, the leading character 1 in the string is implicitly cast to a numeric value 1, which is interpreted as *true* in MySQL.  So it probably works as intended, but kind of by accident.
- The use of `IFNULL()` is so that if either `date_field` or `MAX(exit_date)` is NULL, it returns the row.  If you didn't use this function, then *anything* = NULL would evaluate as *unknown*, which means the row would not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It says basically if table.date_field = max exit date or if max exit_date is null or table.date_field is null return true.  Will return false if max exit_date is not null and table.date_field is not null but they do not equal.